# Limit font glyphs to the glyph a font have

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a UWP app in which I display demo text using different fonts, the problem is, for some fonts, that if the font does not contains certain glyphs it displays those glyphs with a different font.
Examples:

1. If I set the text "The quick brown fox..." in a Textblock using
   EmojiOne the Textblock displays the text using Segoe UI as EmojiOne
   does not contains latin characters (just emojis).
2. If I set the text to a set of emojis, and the font I'm using does not contain those glyphs, the Textblock uses Segoe UI Emoji to display those glyphs.

This does not happens, for example if I use Segoe MDL2 Assets, in which case the textblock only use the glyphs that font contains.

What I need is to force a Textblock to use only the glyphs contained in the font I set, and no resolve missing glyphs with other fonts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share XAML source snippet please?

Comment: I don't think is necessary. Any Textblock, using these fonts in the FontFamily Property has the described behavior.

Comment: What you described is by design. Your requirement might be a feature request. You could submit a **Feature Request** on [WPDev UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/).